# Helping find the S-Curve function from the graph

Tags: curves

I would like to model a function for the S-curve in the [S-Curve Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ds72Q.png). The line in the graph is $y=x$ and the range of the x-axis and y-axis are both (0,1). It seems to be an [incomplete beta function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M02SZ.jpg) or something else. A simpler form would be better. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I found a function $(Sin[(x - 0.5)*\pi] + 1)*0.5$ looks like close. But the intersection point is a little bit right side. It is best if I could control the location of the intersection point.

Answer (score 0):

Take the cubic $y=x(x-\sqrt{2})\left(x-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)$ and rotate the $X$-axis to $y=x$ (i.e., rotate the axes by $-45°$)

That would do I guess.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! But the derivative of this curve at (0,0) and (1,1) probably are not correct.

Comment: What do you want the derivative to be?

Comment: If you have a specific choice of derivative, then you can use $y=kx(x-\sqrt{2})\left(x-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)$ instead and fit $k$ according to the required derivative.